# Cucumber tags running even when excluded (I think)

Tags: ruby, tags, cucumber

This is what I am typing in cygwin:

```
cucumber.bat features -p super
```

This is the super profile:

```
super: FIG_NEWTON_FILE=local.yml --no-source --color --tags ~@nonsuper,~@unimplemented --format pretty
```

This is an example of a test I want to skip:

```
@nonsuper  
Scenario: Try to set denial specials
  Then the "Denial Specialist" field is disabled at the "summary" view
```

It is running scenarios and features with those tags.

I believe I've done something wrong in the profile, I just can't figure out what.

Thanks for any help =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
--tags ~@nonsuper,~@unimplemented
```

It means to run scenarios without the tag `@nonsuper` OR without the tag `@unimplemented`. Your scenario meets the requirement of not having the `@unimplemented` tag, therefore it gets run.

What you want is:

```
--tags ~@nonsuper --tags ~@unimplemented
```

This means to run scenarios without the tag `@nonsuper` AND without the tag `@unimplemented`.

For more details on combining tags see the [tags portion of the Cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags).

Comment: I must have read that 1000 times other places. For some reason, I was under the impression that I would need to have both tags on a scenario for it to not run if I used the AND logic. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip a scenario just put

```
@wip
```

tag in place of '@nonsuper'